# NinevehGL add subview's

Tags: ios, uiview, frameworks

I have this code to create UIView in self.view in fullscreen but i need create in a separated subview

How can i do?

```
File .h

    @private
        NGLMesh *_cube1;
        NGLCamera *_camera;

    }
File .m

    - (void) drawView
    {


        [_camera drawCamera];
    }


    - (void) loadView
    {
        // Following the UIKit specifications, this method should not call the super.

        // Creates the NGLView manually (without XIB), with the screen's size and sets its delegate.


        NGLView *nglView = [[NGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        nglView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        nglView.delegate = self;

        // Sets the NGLView as the root view of this View Controller hierarchy.
        self.view = nglView;

        [nglView release];
    }






    - (void) viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Setting up the multiple touch for this view.
        self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;



        NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                  kNGLMeshCentralizeYes, kNGLMeshKeyCentralize,
                                  @"0.3", kNGLMeshKeyNormalize,
                                  nil];

        _cube1 = [[NGLMesh alloc] initWithFile:@"cube.obj" settings:settings delegate:nil];

    }
```